# Cannot create Member Object if it's part of a parent class

Tags: c++, class, object, member, derived

I tried to create a member object (hope this terminus is correct) and it worked. But if I derive the class of the object it fails. Why is this the case and how do I solve that problem?

```
class test 
{
protected:
    int         id;
public:
    test(){};
    ~test() {};
    test(int a){};
};
/* Without Comments it doesn't work
class derivtest : public test
{

protected:
    int         id;

public:
    derivtest(){};
    ~derivtest() {};
    derivtest(int a){};
}
*/

class test2 
{

public:
    test2():teil(){};
private:
    test teil;
};
```

Comment: How does it "not work"? What kind of error you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be the missing semi-colon after the `derivtest` declaration:

```
class derivtest : public test
{

protected:
    int         id;

public:
    derivtest(){};
    ~derivtest() {};
    derivtest(int a){};
};
 ^ here
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `;` at the end of `derivtest`